# ¿Cómo filtrar un diccionario sin cambiar su arquitectura?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api

Con [Age of Empire API](https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/units) quiero escribir una función que filtre los datos por "edad": hay 4 edades en el juego: Oscura, Feudal, Castillo, Imperial.

- La función debe utilizar los datos de la API como entrada, y tener un parámetro para la edad
- La función debe devolver los datos filtrados

Lo he hecho:

```
url = 'https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/units'
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()

def filter_by_age(data, age):
  if age in ['Dark', 'Feudal', 'Castle', 'Imperial']:
    return [elem for elem in data['units'] if elem['age'] == age]
  else:
    print('error')
filter_by_age(data, 'Dark')
```

Pero parece que filtro la clave `['units']` al principio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es que estés filtrando la clave `units`...lo que pasa es que tu función devuelve un array nuevo que estas creando. Si quieres mantener la estructura igual, puedes crear una estructura igual (hay varias formas de hacerlo, esta es una opción):

```
def filter_by_age(data, age):
  filtered = {'units': []}
  if age in ['Dark', 'Feudal', 'Castle', 'Imperial']:
    filtered['units'] = [elem for elem in data['units'] if elem['age'] == age]
    return filtered
  else:
    print('error')
```